# How to make $\int f\left(\vec{x}\right)x^2d^3{\vec{x}}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics, dirac-delta, probability-limit-theorems

Probability of a certain event is given as $f\left(\vec{x}\right)x^2$. This can be approximated to a delta function as follows
\begin{equation}
f\left(\vec{x}\right)x^2=k\delta^3(\vec{x})
\end{equation}

Here $f$ is a function of $\vec{x}$ and $k$ is a constant. I need to evaluate the value of $k$.

\begin{equation}
k=\int f\left(\vec{x}\right)x^2d^3{\vec{x}}
\end{equation}

What forms can $f$ have so that the value of k does not blow up when I integrate over the whole space.

Also, can a delta function be used as probability? shouldn't probability be finite?

Comment: Not sure if you mean $f(x^2)$ by $f\cdot x^2$.

Comment: I meant $f(x)\cdot x^2$

Comment: The Dirac Delta is NOT a function, it is a distribution (a.k.a. a generalized function).  Furthermore, we have $\langle \phi,\delta \rangle = \phi(0)$ for any suitable test function $\phi$.